# UIButton color change after external event

Tags: ios, uibutton

I need a quick way to change the color of an UIButton live (in response to a delegate call) . So the button is drawn with a white background (standard) then when a delegate call comes it needs to change to a blue/red background.

I tried :

> ```
>    btn.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
>         [btn setNeedsDisplay];
> ```

This doesn't work...

Also it would be a good ideea to change the color of the button text... How is this done????

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using it like this :

```
[button setBackgroundColor:someColor forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Did it work for you .. ? I am assuming you have made your button a custom button type. 
If it worked, you may want to consider, accepting the answer

Answer (score 0):

First make your `UIButton` type Custom..

```
UIButton* myButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];

[myButton setbackgroundColor:[UIColor blueColor] forState: UIControlStateNormal];
[myButton setTitleColor:[UIColor blueColor] forState: UIControlStateNormal];
```